# Syncing changes on Docker Bitnami/WordPress + WSL Ubuntu mounted volume

Tags: docker, bitnami

*Sorry if this question seems everywhere. I've been searching non-stop on Google, debugging with ChatGPT, overall have trouble finding reliable information to debug this.*

I'm at 24 HOURS of trying to setup Docker + Bitnami/WordPress in Windows 10. Made progress after installing WSL2 + Ubuntu + mounting volumes (page load speed decreased from 90-250 secs to 0.5 secs per page).

But now I don't understand how to use this as a local development environment, aka. PHP debugger + syncing files from Windows to Ubuntu volume mount.

(1) When I develop, I make 1000x incremental changes and check to see what is happening, errors thrown, etc. Don't know how to setup a watch to update my files in the WSL Ubuntu mount.

Folders I'm using:

- Source: `C:\dev\domain.com\wordpress` (Windows 10)
- Target: `/home/my_user/volumes/wordpress` (WSL2 Ubuntu-22.04)

When I had set the WSL2 Ubuntu mount initially, I used `mv /mnt/c/source_dir /home/{user}/target_dir`.

Wondering what's the right way to do this?

I tried using `inotifywait` with `rsync` using a shell script that I run inside WSL Ubuntu, but it doesn't see when I change a file in Windows:

```
#!/bin/bash

source_dir="/mnt/c/dev/docker_package/volumes/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/{my_plugin}/"
target_dir="~/volumes/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/{my_plugin}/"

while true; do
    inotifywait -r -e modify,create,delete,move "$source_dir"
    rsync -av --progress "$source_dir" "$target_dir"
done
```

(2) Also, is there a way to setup PHP Debugging from Bitnami/Wordpress to my IDE?

(3) My WordPress has custom plugin that generates PDF files using TCPDF. It works on `AWS LightSail: Bitnami/WordPress`. For some reason, it's not working locally, can't even `mkdir` in the target directory. There's no errors being thrown anywhere, apache `error_log` is empty, nothing in Docker Desktop logs. I already chmod/chown entire `/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content` directory, still not working or throwing errors.

I wonder if maybe Docker Bitnami/WordPress has fewer PHP libraries than AWS LightSail Bitnami/WordPress, and if maybe I need to install a missing php lib?

But I'm not getting any errors anywhere right now, so really confused.

(4) Does `Docker: Bitnami/WordPress` come with a cron runner? I added a cron task into `/etc/cron.d` and restarted server, but it's not getting run.

(5) What's the system user with privileges on `Docker: Bitnami/WordPress`? I'm seeing `root`, `1001`, and an occasional `daemon`. Not sure what my `/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content` needs to be using. But looks like it's different from AWS LightSail (which seems to use `bitnami`).

---

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  wordpress:
    image: bitnami/wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
      - "443:8443"
      - "22:2222"  # Expose SSH for SFTP access
    environment:
      - "WORDPRESS_SKIP_BOOTSTRAP=yes"
      - "WORDPRESS_DATABASE_HOST=mariadb"
      - "WORDPRESS_DATABASE_PORT_NUMBER=3306"
      - "WORDPRESS_DATABASE_USER={user}"
      - "WORDPRESS_DATABASE_PASSWORD={pass}"
      - "WORDPRESS_DATABASE_NAME={dbname}"
      - "WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX=wp_"
    volumes:
      - "wordpress_data:/bitnami/wordpress"
      - ./volumes/conf/cron/wp-cron:/etc/cron.d/wp-cron  # Cron task
      - ./volumes/conf/ssh/ida_rsa.pub:/home/bitnami/.ssh/authorized_keys   # SSH *.pub
      - ./volumes/conf/vhosts/htaccess/wordpress-htaccess.conf:/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/htaccess/wordpress-htaccess.conf:ro   # .htaccess
      - ./volumes/conf/vhosts/wordpress-vhost.conf:/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/wordpress-vhost.conf:ro   # http:80
      - ./volumes/conf/vhosts/wordpress-https-vhost.conf:/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/wordpress-https-vhost.conf:ro   # https:443
      - ./volumes/conf/certs/server.crt:/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/server.crt:ro  # SSL *.crt
      - ./volumes/conf/certs/server.key:/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/server.key:ro   # SSL *.key
    networks:
      - wordpress_network

  mariadb:
    image: bitnami/mariadb:latest
    environment:
      - "ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes"
      - "MARIADB_USER=dbmasteruser"
      - "MARIADB_PASSWORD={pass}"
      - "MARIADB_DATABASE={dbname}"
      - "MARIADB_CHARACTER_SET=utf8mb4"
      - "MARIADB_COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci"
      - "MARIADB_SKIP_TEST_DB=yes"
      - "MARIADB_ENABLE_SLOW_QUERY=1"
      - "MARIADB_LONG_QUERY_TIME=5"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"  # Expose MariaDB on port 3306
    volumes:
      - ./init/mysql/db_dump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-startdb.d/db_dump.sql
      - "mariadb_data:/bitnami/mariadb"
    networks:
      - wordpress_network

  memcached:
    image: bitnami/memcached:latest
    ports:
      - "11211:11211"
    environment:
      - MEMCACHED_CACHE_SIZE=512 
    networks:
      - wordpress_network

networks:
  wordpress_network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  wordpress_data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: /home/bitnami/volumes/wordpress
  mariadb_data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: ./volumes/mariadb
```